# Google authentication in RShiny stuck at "Just a moment"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, shiny, google-oauth, googleauthr

I'm fairly new to programming and am trying to implement Google authentication in my Shiny app using the `googleAuthR` package - I've been trying to run the sample code listed for the googleSignIn module [here](https://code.markedmondson.me/googleAuthR/articles/google-authentication-types.html#googlesignin-module-example).

I've set up a Google client ID following the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/get-google-api-clientid) but attempting to sign in using it results in the popup saying "Just a moment..." before disappearing without signing the user in. I believe this might be an issue with my setup of the Google client ID as replacing my client ID with the one provided in [this working example](https://github.com/dkulp2/Google-Sign-In) works and allows login. Is there something I've missed in setting up the API client?

Comment: I wonder if this relates to my problem (https://stackapps.com/q/10497/55248). I'm getting `GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: \`POST https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/access_token/json\` resulted in a \`403 Forbidden\` response:
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/htm (truncated...)
 in /mnt/c/code/stackExchangeBackupDemo2/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113`